# Aggregating data in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

> Any ideas on how i can implement aggregation for my voting data visualization?
>    This is my dataset properties

```
var newPoll = {
id: uuid(),
title: req.body.title,
time: new Date().toISOString(),
options: req.body.options,
votes: []
};`
```

I'm thinking of appending user option to votes array basing on what the user selected and doing aggregation on the votes array dataset

Comment: Can you please tag your question with the programming language you're using?

Comment: You can use third party library like lodash or Underscore.Js.